# jquery events and backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am having issues with an events firing twice when clicked, what I am trying to open a div that is collapsable on the click of a link and then close again on a second click. The problem is that the link is one of many with the same class and the same functionality on the page. And what happens is the open event happens immediately followed by the close event,

I am not sure why this is happening, as I am identifying the clicked element using,

`e.currentTarget();`

but it seems to be getting confused as to what element is getting clicked.

Here is my code,

**Open the div**

```
itemTab: function(e) {

    var clicked = $(e.currentTarget),
        clickedTab = clicked.data("tab");

    clicked.parent().parent().parent().find(".action-btn").css({
        "width" : "0px",
        "display" : "none"
    });

    clicked.parent().find("div.action-btn").show().animate({
        "width" : "28px"
    }, 250);

    //clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find("li#active").attr("id", "");
    clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
    clicked.closest(".items-tabs").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
    clicked.parent().addClass("active").attr("id", "active");
    clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find(".tab-content.active").removeClass("active");
    clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find("." + clickedTab).addClass("active");
    clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find(".close").css("visibility", "visible");

    e.preventDefault();
},
```

**close the div**

```
closeTab: function(e) {

            var clicked = $(e.currentTarget).parent(),
                    clickedTab = clicked.data("tab");

            clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find(".tab-content.active").slideUp(500, function() {
                    clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find(".tab-content.active").removeClass("active");
            });

            clicked.removeClass("active");

            e.preventDefault();

    },
```

**The HTML**

```
 <article class="item">

    <header class="active">
        <h1>
            <span class="expander"></span>
            <span class="item_name editable">New Item</span>
            <span class="js-complete-item complete-item ">=</span>
            <span class="fileinputbar-button js-open-adder-form add-item-task">+</span>

            <ul class="floating-menu">
                    <span class="tip"></span>
                    <li class="js-add-new-task add-new-task"><a href="#">Add Task</a></li>


                    <li class="js-add-new-item add-new-item"><a href="#">Add Item</a></li>

            </ul>
            <span class="tasks meta">

            <span class="js-task-count">6 / 6 tasks</span>
            <span class="js-completion-status"></span>



        </span></h1>


        <div class="inline-edit item" style="display: none;">


            <form action="/projects/items/edit/71" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="item_name" class="inline_edit edit_item_name" novalidate="novalidate">              

                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="item_name" value="New Item" class="item_name">         
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
                    <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>

                        <a href="/projects/items/delete/71" class="delete js-delete-item">Delete</a>

                </p>
                    </form>





        </div>

        <div class="percentage_bar" title="0% Complete" style="background-color: #18fbc5; width: 0%;">0% Complete</div>
    </header>



    <div class="item_content" style="display: block;">
        <div class="item-tabs">
            <ul class="tab-links">
                <li class="active" id="active"><div></div><a href="" class="item-tab" data-tab="description">Description</a><div></div></li>
                <li class="" id="active"><div></div><a href="" class="item-tab" data-tab="tasks" style="color: red;">Tasks</a><div></div><div class="action-btn js-add-tasks" style="width: 0px; display: none;"></div></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content description active">
                <span class="item_description editable">
                    <p class="add-text js-add-item-description">

                            <span class="faded">No Description, Click to add</span>

                    </p>
                </span>
                <div class="inline-edit js-item-description-edit" style="display: none;">
                    <form action="/projects/items/edit_description/71" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="item_description" class="inline_edit edit_item_description" novalidate="novalidate">                
                        <p>
                            <textarea autofocus="" name="item_description" class="edit_item_description"></textarea>
                            <!--<input type="text" name="item_description" value="" class="edit_item_description"> -->
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">                  
                            <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content tasks"><article class="task-list"> 

    <header>
        <h1 class="tasks active">
            <span class="js-task-header">Tasks</span>
            <span class="fileinputbar-button js-open-task-adder-form list-header-add">+</span>
        </h1>
    </header>
        <div class="tasks active">
        <span class="toggle-header">
            <div class="labels">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="label" id="active">Active<i class="close-label"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="label" id="completed">Complete<i class="close-label"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                <input id="user-search-query" type="text" name="task_search" value="" placeholder="Filter" class="required file-search">


</span><div class="new-task js-new-task" style="display: none;">
                <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="inline-edit inline_edit edit_task_name" novalidate="novalidate" style="display: none;">
                    <p>
                        <textarea autofocus="" name="task_name" class="item task_name_edit js-task-adder-input" title="Add New Task (Press Enter to add)" placeholder="New task name..."></textarea><a href="#" class="js-task-adder-addbutton"></a>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="js-task-adder-input-submit">
                        <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                        <span class="instruction-task-add">Press Enter to add, or shift enter to add a new line</span> 
                    </p>
                </form>

                <a href="/projects/items/stages/tasks/add/12" title="Add New Task" class="js-task-adder-add-new-task js-task-adder-trigger" data-url="/projects/items/stages/tasks/add" data-id="12"></a>
</div>
    <ol class="tasks active"><div name="dasdsadas" task_id="129" id="129" item="New Item" item_id="71" creator="simonainley" created_by="1" created_on="2013-09-26T14:39:23+01:00" completion_date="1999-11-30T01:00:00+00:00" completed="active" parent_id="71" parent_type="item" project_id="12">
    <li class="">
    <h5><span class="task_name editable">dasdsadas</span>


        <form action="/tasks/edit/129" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="inline-edit inline_edit edit_task_name" novalidate="novalidate" style="display: none;">          <p>
                <textarea name="task_name" class="task_name_edit">dasdsadas</textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">              <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                <a href="/items/stages/tasks/delete/dasdsadas" title="Delete Task" class="delete">delete</a>            </p>
        </form>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </h5>
            <div class="meta">
                <span>Created by Me <time datetime="2013-09-26T14:39:23+01:00" title="2013-09-26T14:39:23+01:00">5 days ago</time>
                </span>






     <span class="path">

        [ <span class="item">New Item</span>
         ] 
     </span>


            </div>


            <div class="update">
                    <a href="#" title="Complete this task" class="complete js-complete-task" data-url="/tasks/toggle_complete/129" data-id="129">active</a>
            </div>


        </li>
</div><div name="sdasdas" task_id="127" id="127" item="New Item" item_id="71" creator="simonainley" created_by="1" created_on="2013-09-25T16:26:07+01:00" completion_date="1999-11-30T01:00:00+00:00" completed="active" parent_id="71" parent_type="item" project_id="12">
    <li class="">
    <h5><span class="task_name editable">sdasdas</span>


        <form action="/tasks/edit/127" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="inline-edit inline_edit edit_task_name" novalidate="novalidate" style="display: none;">          <p>
                <textarea name="task_name" class="task_name_edit">sdasdas</textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">              <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                <a href="/projects/items/stages/tasks/delete/sdasdas" title="Delete Task" class="delete">delete</a>         </p>
        </form>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </h5>
            <div class="meta">
                <span>Created by Me <time datetime="2013-09-25T16:26:07+01:00" title="2013-09-25T16:26:07+01:00">6 days ago</time>
                </span>






     <span class="path">

        [ <span class="item">New Item</span>
         ] 
     </span>


            </div>


            <div class="update">
                    <a href="#" title="Complete this task" class="complete js-complete-task" data-url="/tasks/toggle_complete/127" data-id="127">active</a>
            </div>


        </li>
</div><div name="New Sub Item Task 2" task_id="124" id="124" item="New Item" item_id="71" creator="simonainley" created_by="1" created_on="2013-09-25T09:43:00+01:00" completion_date="1999-11-30T01:00:00+00:00" completed="active" parent_id="71" parent_type="item" project_id="12">
    <li class="">
    <h5><span class="task_name editable">New Sub Item Task 2</span>


        <form action="/tasks/edit/124" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="inline-edit inline_edit edit_task_name" novalidate="novalidate" style="display: none;">          <p>
                <textarea name="task_name" class="task_name_edit">New Sub Item Task 2</textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">              <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                <a href="/projects/items/stages/tasks/delete/New Sub Item Task 2" title="Delete Task" class="delete">delete</a>         </p>
        </form>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </h5>
            <div class="meta">
                <span>Created by Me <time datetime="2013-09-25T09:43:00+01:00" title="2013-09-25T09:43:00+01:00">6 days ago</time>
                </span>






     <span class="path">

        [ <span class="item">New Item</span>
         ] 
     </span>


            </div>


            <div class="update">
                    <a href="#" title="Complete this task" class="complete js-complete-task" data-url="/tasks/toggle_complete/124" data-id="124">active</a>
            </div>


        </li>
</div><div name="New Sub Item Task 1" task_id="123" id="123" item="New Item" item_id="71" creator="simonainley" created_by="1" created_on="2013-09-25T09:42:48+01:00" completion_date="1999-11-30T01:00:00+00:00" completed="active" parent_id="71" parent_type="item" project_id="12">
    <li class="">
    <h5><span class="task_name editable">New Sub Item Task 1</span>


        <form action="/tasks/edit/123" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="inline-edit inline_edit edit_task_name" novalidate="novalidate" style="display: none;">          <p>
                <textarea name="task_name" class="task_name_edit">New Sub Item Task 1</textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">              <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                <a href="/projects/items/stages/tasks/delete/New Sub Item Task 1" title="Delete Task" class="delete">delete</a>         </p>
        </form>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </h5>
            <div class="meta">
                <span>Created by Me <time datetime="2013-09-25T09:42:48+01:00" title="2013-09-25T09:42:48+01:00">6 days ago</time>
                </span>






     <span class="path">

        [ <span class="item">New Item</span>
         ] 
     </span>


            </div>


            <div class="update">
                    <a href="#" title="Complete this task" class="complete js-complete-task" data-url="/tasks/toggle_complete/123" data-id="123">active</a>
            </div>


        </li>
</div>
    </ol>
        </div>
</article></div>
        </div>
    <article class="item">

    <header class="active">
        <h1>
            <span class="expander"></span>
            <span class="item_name editable">New Item Sub Item</span>
            <span class="js-complete-item complete-item ">=</span>
            <span class="fileinputbar-button js-open-adder-form add-item-task">+</span>

            <ul class="floating-menu">
                    <span class="tip"></span>
                    <li class="js-add-new-task add-new-task"><a href="#">Add Task</a></li>


            </ul>
            <span class="tasks meta">

            <span class="js-task-count">2 / 2 tasks</span>
            <span class="js-completion-status"></span>



        </span></h1>


        <div class="inline-edit item" style="display: none;">


            <form action="/projects/items/edit/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="item_name" class="inline_edit edit_item_name" novalidate="novalidate">                

                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="item_name" value="New Item Sub Item" class="item_name">            
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
                    <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>

                        <a href="/projects/items/delete/" class="delete js-delete-item">Delete</a>

                </p>
                    </form>





        </div>

        <div class="percentage_bar" title="0% Complete" style="background-color: #18fbc5; width: 0%;">0% Complete</div>
    </header>



    <div class="item_content" style="display: block;">
        <div class="item-tabs">
            <ul class="tab-links">
                <li class=""><div></div><a href="" class="item-tab" data-tab="description">Description</a><div></div></li>
                <li class="active" id="active"><div></div><a href="" class="item-tab" data-tab="tasks" style="color: red;">Tasks</a><div></div><div class="action-btn js-add-tasks" style="width: 28px; display: block;"></div></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content description">
                <span class="item_description editable">
                    <p class="add-text js-add-item-description">

                            <span class="faded">No Description, Click to add</span>

                    </p>
                </span>
                <div class="inline-edit js-item-description-edit" style="display: none;">
                    <form action="/projects/items/edit_description/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="item_description" class="inline_edit edit_item_description" novalidate="novalidate">              
                        <p>
                            <textarea autofocus="" name="item_description" class="edit_item_description"></textarea>
                            <!--<input type="text" name="item_description" value="" class="edit_item_description"> -->
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">                  
                            <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content tasks active"><article class="task-list"> 

    <header>
        <h1 class="tasks active">
            <span class="js-task-header">Tasks</span>
            <span class="fileinputbar-button js-open-task-adder-form list-header-add">+</span>
        </h1>
    </header>
        <div class="tasks active">
        <span class="toggle-header">
            <div class="labels">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="label" id="active">Active<i class="close-label"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="label" id="completed">Complete<i class="close-label"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                <input id="user-search-query" type="text" name="task_search" value="" placeholder="Filter" class="required file-search">


</span><div class="new-task js-new-task" style="display: none;">
                <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="inline-edit inline_edit edit_task_name" novalidate="novalidate" style="display: none;">
                    <p>
                        <textarea autofocus="" name="task_name" class="item task_name_edit js-task-adder-input" title="Add New Task (Press Enter to add)" placeholder="New task name..."></textarea><a href="#" class="js-task-adder-addbutton"></a>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="js-task-adder-input-submit">
                        <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                        <span class="instruction-task-add">Press Enter to add, or shift enter to add a new line</span> 
                    </p>
                </form>

                <a href="/projects/items/stages/tasks/add/12" title="Add New Task" class="js-task-adder-add-new-task js-task-adder-trigger" data-url="/projects/items/stages/tasks/add" data-id="12"></a>
</div>
    <ol class="tasks active"><div id="130" name="A new task!" task_id="130" item="New Item" item_id="71" creator="simonainley" created_by="1" created_on="2013-09-26T14:40:17+01:00" completion_date="1999-11-30T01:00:00+00:00" stage="New Item Sub Item" stage_id="74" completed="active" parent_id="74" parent_type="item" project_id="12">
    <li class="">
    <h5><span class="task_name editable">A new task!</span>


        <form action="/tasks/edit/130" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="inline-edit inline_edit edit_task_name" novalidate="novalidate" style="display: none;">          <p>
                <textarea name="task_name" class="task_name_edit">A new task!</textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">              <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                <a href="/projects/items/stages/tasks/delete/A new task!" title="Delete Task" class="delete">delete</a>         </p>
        </form>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </h5>
            <div class="meta">
                <span>Created by Me <time datetime="2013-09-26T14:40:17+01:00" title="2013-09-26T14:40:17+01:00">5 days ago</time>
                </span>






     <span class="path">

        [ <span class="item">New Item</span>

             / <span class="stage"> New Item Sub Item</span> ] 

     </span>


            </div>


            <div class="update">
                    <a href="#" title="Complete this task" class="complete js-complete-task" data-url="/tasks/toggle_complete/130" data-id="130">active</a>
            </div>


        </li>
</div><div id="128" name="Boom!" task_id="128" item="New Item" item_id="71" creator="simonainley" created_by="1" created_on="2013-09-25T17:18:49+01:00" completion_date="1999-11-30T01:00:00+00:00" stage="New Item Sub Item" stage_id="74" completed="active" parent_id="74" parent_type="item" project_id="12">
    <li class="">
    <h5><span class="task_name editable">Boom!</span>


        <form action="/tasks/edit/128" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="inline-edit inline_edit edit_task_name" novalidate="novalidate" style="display: none;">          <p>
                <textarea name="task_name" class="task_name_edit">Boom!</textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">              <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                <a href="/items/stages/tasks/delete/Boom!" title="Delete Task" class="delete">delete</a>            </p>
        </form>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </h5>
            <div class="meta">
                <span>Created by Me <time datetime="2013-09-25T17:18:49+01:00" title="2013-09-25T17:18:49+01:00">6 days ago</time>
                </span>






     <span class="path">

        [ <span class="item">New Item</span>

             / <span class="stage"> New Item Sub Item</span> ] 

     </span>


            </div>


            <div class="update">
                    <a href="#" title="Complete this task" class="complete js-complete-task" data-url="/tasks/toggle_complete/128" data-id="128">active</a>
            </div>


        </li>
</div>
    </ol>
        </div>
</article></div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- item_content:end -->
</article></div><!-- item_content:end -->
</article>
```

**The Events**

```
events : {
    "click .item-tabs li:not(.active) a": "itemTab",
    "click .item-tabs li.active": "closeTab",
}
```

Is there are reason why the event is running the open and close event straight after one another?

Comment: It's strange, I added your code in my BackboneJS code, and your situation is not happening to me. When I click to a link with active class is closeTab function launched, and when I click in a link child of an li with no active class, itemTab is launched. Never I get the both functions launched at the same click. Do you have a similar listeners or a view parent of another with the same view? Sometimes a view contains another, like the selectors are the same a function is launched two times. With this different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find out which element is clicked:

```
console.log($(e.currentTarget));
console.log($(e.target));
```

This should output clicked HTML element to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Check `isDefaultPrevented` before executing you code might solve your problem for Example:

```
closeTab: function(e) {
    if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()) { // Add this condition to both functions
        var clicked = $(e.currentTarget).parent(),
                clickedTab = clicked.data("tab");

        clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find(".tab-content.active").slideUp(500, function() {
                clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find(".tab-content.active").removeClass("active");
        });

        clicked.removeClass("active");

        e.preventDefault();
    }
},
```